# Regular expression for email using look ahead in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for email.

For the characters before @ symbol, I want following rules to be obeyed:
 `a-z,A-Z,0-9` are allowed along with special character `-,.,_`

I write expression in java like `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}(?=[.-_]?+)"` for text before @ symbol.

But it is also allowing "ddff....." i.e. multiple dots are getting allowed, which should not be the case as I have used ?+ quantifier. It should fail.

Can anyone help on this?

```
public class EmailRegex {
private static String EMAIL_REGEX_NEW_2="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}(?=[.-_]?+)";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the email name to validate");
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        if (!serverValidationUsingRegexPattern(sc.nextLine(), EMAIL_REGEX_NEW_2)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, Email name invalid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congrats, Email name valid");
        }
    }
}
public static boolean serverValidationUsingRegexPattern(
    String valueToValidate, String regexPattern) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(valueToValidate);
    return m.find();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1) Change your regex e.g. to this.

```
private static String EMAIL_REGEX_NEW_2 = 
        "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}([.-_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})*$";
```

Note: this is just a regex for the text before the @ symbol.

2) Don't call `find()`, call `matches()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailRegex {
    private static String EMAIL_REGEX_NEW_2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}([.-_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})*$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the email name to validate");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (!serverValidationUsingRegexPattern(sc.nextLine(), EMAIL_REGEX_NEW_2)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, Email name invalid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congrats, Email name valid");
        }
    }

    public static boolean serverValidationUsingRegexPattern(String valueToValidate, String regexPattern) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(valueToValidate);
        return m.matches();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thanks. But in case I have to use look ahead, than we need to use find()

Comment: Yeah, I am not good at look ahead. So I prefer to keep it simple :) I don't consider using them a very good practice too.

Answer (score 1):

The full regex for email is

```
"[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})"
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use lookahead to match until `@` is next character.
- Your use of lookahead isn't correct for special characters.
- Hyphen needs to be at first or last position inside character class to be unescaped.
- Use negative lookahead `(?!.*?[._-]{2})` to make sure 2 special characters don't appear twice.

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?[._-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(?=@)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mI4pK9/1)